# EL expression with "or" operator or "in" function

Tags: el

I want to set a EL expression where if the values are 1 or 2, then a field will be enabled or else not

```html
#{bindings.ReqBuId.inputValue==1} || {bindings.ReqBuId.inputValue==2} ? true : false
```

Is this expression valid ? 
Secondly,is there an 'In' functionality i can use in EL?

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: Is it also possible to copy value from one column to another using EL? Scenario:There are two columns Column A and Column B. If Column A is populated with a value, Column B should also have the same value copied from Column A

Answer (score 1):

No, your expression is not valid. I'm assuming you are using `String` values, in that case use:

```html
#{bindings.ReqBuId.inputValue == '1' or bindings.ReqBuId.inputValue == '2'}
```

There is no `in` in EL, but you could use a `Collection` of `Strings`s and on that use `contains(yourString)`. In EL 3.0+ you can do this like:

```html
#{['1','2'].contains(bindings.ReqBuId.inputValue)}
```

Comment: In EL 3.0 you can use `${[1,2].contains(bean.property)}`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please give an example how to use a Collection of Objects and on that use contains(yourObject).